# Is there any way to create a light that does what world lighting does? ie. Diffuse "non-directional" scene lighting?

Tags: lighting, world

I find world lighting helpful for giving objects a bit of slight illumination from all angles. Eg. Designing 3D icons/buttons. In this application, I am using world lighting with a flat white color, surface is "background" and strength 1-2 range.

Is there any way to set up a light in the scene that accomplishes the same or a similar thing? Ie. scattered lighting diffusely from all angles?

The reason I am interested is that for example in my current project, I am rendering my buttons in a brighter lighting (activated) and lower lighting (de-activated) setting. I would rather have a light I can turn on/off in the scene than be constantly changing the world lighting and worrying if I am going to remember how I set it 2 years from now if I want to change something again.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Hi :). You could add a large sphere with Emission node around your whole scene, and turn it on/off for renders.

Comment: Thanks Jachym. I think that would work for Cycles but not Eevee. I usually just use Eevee as it's faster. But appreciate the thought and if I'm using Cycles I'll try that.